# SQL get min/max from a table

Tags: sql

SQL - how to get the min/max values of a column in a table

Comment: select max(column) as maxValue from table - now access via columnname  "maxValue"

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/min.php

Comment: Must search or check some tutorials, before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we create new table:

```
CREATE TABLE PrmTable
(
   ID INT,
   Value BIGINT
)
```

Create new table with the requested operators:

```
SELECT MaxValue = MAX(Value) , MinValue = MIN(Value)
FROM PrmTable
WHERE .....
```

Answer (score 6):

To select the [minimum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) of a column:

```
SELECT MIN(columnName) FROM table;
```

and to select the [maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) of a column:

```
SELECT MAX(columnName) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions:

```
SELECT MAX(column) AS max, MIN(column) AS min
  FROM table
```

Have you read a documentation or just check Google for ANY answer ?